# Windows 7 up/left arrow keys commands

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

OK, I've attempted to find answers for this issue here and elsewhere and it is driving me insane.

I'm on a corporate issue Lenovo w530 laptop [aka HUGEBRICK] running Windows 7.

Somehow the up and left arrow keys have assumed some sort of uber command mode in windows apps including Word and Outlook. Now, these arrows cannot be used to move throughout text in these apps, but only to minimize and close windows (and no, I am not holding down and CTRL/WIN/FUN keys at the same time).

I'm thinking somehow some Windows shortcut or damn Sticky key type setting is turned on. I've attempted to follow tutorials and turn off Sticky keys to no avail. I've swapped keyboard settings to another language and back again... still can't get them to work as they typically do.

I just want to use these keys while editing text and its killing me.

Comment: Did you try a reboot? Did you try asking your "corporate issue" IT support?

Comment: For me, Windows sometimes locks modifier keys for seemingly no reason. Have you tried hitting each of CTRL/WIN/FUN keys (just the key itself,  not in combination) to see if it resets its state?  I suspect the (one or both) Windows keys since WIN+UP and WIN+DOWN are max and min shortcuts